# geckodriver opens an extra window on running test cases

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

This issue happens randomly upon launching the test

Window 10

Firefox 55

geckodriver 0.18.0

selenium-java-3.4.0

test run is paused until I manually close the extra window (to the left in the image)

Any idea how to avoid this issue ?

```
public static WebDriver createWebDriver(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "lib\\geckodriver.exe");

    return new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have got same, no need to close it, it is close automatically

Comment: @iamsankalp89 Thanks you but I confirm that it doesn't auto close for me. (I tried again after your comment and it exceeded 5 minutes and counting without closing)

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Please try this code and let me know still u facing same issue